# I am learning two pointers and I am trying to solve the return the unique elements in an Arraylist question using two pointers whats wrong with mycode

Tags: data-structures

//what is wrong in my code which is trying to find the unique elements in an arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> Unique_element (ArrayList<Integer> A){
int N = A.size();// 11
ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
  int p1 = 0;

  while(p1 <=N-2){ // 0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4,5,6,7,8,9
  if(!A.get(p1).equals(A.get(p1+1)) ){
    ans.add(A.get(p1));
    p1++;
  }
  else if(A.get(p1).equals(A.get(p1+1))){
    int left = A.get(p1);
    while(A.get(p1).equals(left)){
      
      p1++;
    }
  }
```

}
return ans;

}

//the answer i was expecting was 7 56 19 12 11 what I was getting 56 19 12 11

Comment: So couple of things your loop might go out of bounds with `n-2` and the issue in your code lies in the section where you handle consecutive duplicate elements where you are correctly skipping over them in the input array, but you're not adding the unique element to the `ans` ArrayList.

Comment: Also where have you declared the second pointer?

Comment: Oh ok thank you got the error